# Permalink and add_rewrite_rule in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, permalinks

In my theme, I have two files: `seller.php` and `seller-detail.php`.

In `seller.php`, I get data from the custom table `wp_ma_seller` and show it as a list of items.

I used `<a class="item-link" href="<?php echo home_url('/seller/id=' . $item['id']); ?>"></a>` for each item.

My issue is I want to enter `seller-detail.php` and show ID of item.

I had customed Permalink in Setting to `localhost/ma/%postname%/id=%post_id%` and created this rewrite rule in `functions.php`

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
add_rewrite_rule('/seller/id=([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?pagename=seller&seller_id=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule');
```

What should I do to WordPress can know to enter `seller-detail.php`?

Comment: Flush the rules after adding. But only once (on plugin activate for example). More information can be had here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/#comment-3503